# Dynamically splitting an array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, associative-array

I'm trying to build a function that will split an array of strings into
a) a hashtable with [x] arrays of strings -or-
b) x arrays of strings

What I have now is the following:

```
Function Split-Array {
    Param (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [array]$arrToSplit,

        # Param2 help description
        [int]$SplitInTo = 8
    )

        $Round = 0 
        $hashSplitted = @{}

        For ($i = 0 ; $i -le ($SplitInTo -1) ; $i++ ) {
            New-Variable -Name "arrPartial$i" -Value @()
            }

        While (($Round * $SplitInTo) -le $arrToSplit.Count) {
            For ($i = 0 ; $i -le ($SplitInTo - 1) ; $i++) {
                $arrDynamicVariable = Get-Variable -name "arrPartial$i" -ValueOnly
                $arrDynamicVariable += $arrToSplit[($Round * $SplitInTo) + $i]
                Set-Variable -Name "arrPartial$i" -Value $arrDynamicVariable
                }
            $Round++
            }

        For ($i = 0 ; $i -le ($SplitInTo -1) ; $i++) {
            $hashSplitted[$i] = Get-Variable -Name "arrPartial$i" -ValueOnly
            }
        $hashSplitted
    }
```

Where it seems to go wrong is the "Get-Variable" part. Powershell gives an error:

> Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name 'arrPartial8'. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Get-Variable -name "arrPartial$i" -ValueOnly
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (arrPartial8:String) [Get-Variable], I 
>       temNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetVari 
>       ableCommand

Oddly, the arrPartial variables seems to be created, but it's a little different from an variable declared by e.g. "$arra = @()", as shown below:

```
PS Variable:\> dir

Name                           Value                                                 
----                           -----                                                 
$                              )                                                     
?                              True                                                  
^                              $arra                                                 
args                           {}                                                    
arra                           {}                                                    
arrPartial0                   {}                                                    
arrPartial1                   {}                                                    
arrPartial2                   {}                                                    
arrPartial3                   {}                                                    
arrPartial4                   {}                                                    
arrPartial5                   {}                                                    
arrPartial6                   {}                                                    
arrPartial7                   {}
```

Notice the fact the arrPartialx arrays have their {} indented to the left. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here? Any ideas for different ways to do this are welcome.

Comment: I copy and pasted this and ran against an array of my own and got no such error. Have you tried in a fresh console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to "fold" a one-dimensional array

```
[ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j ]
```

into a hashtable like this (assuming `$SplitInTo = 3` for simplicity reasons)?

```
{
  arrPartial0 => [ a, d, g, j ]
  arrPartial1 => [ b, e, h ]
  arrPartial2 => [ c, f, i ]
}
```

If so, you're making this *way* too complicated. Something like this should suffice:

```
function Invoke-FoldArray {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [array]$arrToSplit,
    [int]$SplitInTo = 8
  )

  $ht = [ordered]@{}

  0..($SplitInTo-1) | % {
    $ht["arrPartial$_"] = @()
  }

  $i = 0
  $arrToSplit | % {
    $ht["arrPartial$i"] += $_
    $i++
    $i %= $SplitInTo
  }

  return $ht
}
```

Comment: You could even assign with `[array]$ht["arrPartial$i"] += $_` and skip the first loop entirely

Comment: Thanks Ansgar Wiechers! Thats exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: Sorry about that, new to stackoverflow. Definitely solved the problem :)